# I need to have moving average on a window of 5 rows and 2 columns same row might have same value (see the details)

Tags: sql, function, window, lag, partition

the table I have is like:

```
year_round
home_team_name
away_team_name
home_kicks
away_kicks
```

I need moving average on `home_kicks` and `away_kicks`. In one record there are `home_kicks` and `away_kicks`. For home kicks I need also to calculate same team when it is as away kicks in previous rounds. At the moment I use a veery complex and slow query. I want to use partition and window functions of new SQL. I cannot get my head around this. I know how to do moving average with partition and window function for one column like `home_kicks` but I cannot add here same team when it plays as away team in previous rounds.

```
select fms.year_round ,
avg(fms.home_kicks) over (partition by fms.home_team_name order by fms.year_round desc range between 5 preceding and 1 preceding) as avg_home_kicks_5 
from fw_matches_stats fms 
order by fms.year_round desc
```

I guess I need to self inner join to select home_team as away_team but not sure how to do the calculations.

Comment: Your query looks fine, what does your table look like including keys an indexes? For your other question some sample data would help. You can use https://dbfiddle.uk/ to setup the scenario and then update your post with the url

Comment: The query I wrote as example is only for the part of what I need. The end goal is average of home team to include data when this team plays as away team. In football same team can be home and away team. I need stats of moving average  per home team including both case: when it plays as home team and always team